# How to validate a drop down list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

How can I validate a drop down list?
I have a "Material Requested" column and a "Issued" or "Returned" column.
If a item gets requested we choose issued. 
I want to make sure the Item is returned before it get issued again. 
Basically, I want to enforce unique values on the "Material Requested" Column

Answer (score 0):

That means, you want a “Material Requested” to be able to be issued only after it is returned.

You can enforce unique values for “Material Requested” column. This feature prevents users from duplicating data.

[image]

If user wants to issue/return the existing “Material Requested”, he can only edit the item and modify "Issued/Returned" column to set the status. So that, user cannot issue “Material Requested” again before it get returned.

Comment: The "Material Requested" is a multiple choice, Drop down.
When I enforced the unique values it doesn't let me issued anything unless I returned the previous material.